# What does the output of dpkg -l means?

Tags: command-line, dpkg

The command `dpkg -l` is used to list all installed packages in the system.

But if you look to the output such as below:

```
ii  whoopsie       0.1.34         Ubuntu crash database submission daemon
rc  wicd-daemon    1.7.2.3-1ubunt wired and wireless network manager - daemon
rc  wicd-gtk       1.7.2.3-1ubunt wired and wireless network manager - GTK+ cl
ii  winbind        2:3.6.3-2ubunt Samba nameservice integration server
ii  wine           1:1.7.18-0ubun Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (meta-
ii  wine-gecko2.21 2.21-0ubuntu1~ Microsoft Windows compatibility layer (embed
ii  wine-gecko2.21 2.21-0ubuntu1~ Microsoft Windows compatibility layer (embed
ii  wine-mono0.0.8 0.0.8-0ubuntu1 Microsoft Windows compatibility layer (.NET 
rc  wine1.4        1.4.1-0ubuntu1 Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (Binar
rc  wine1.4-amd64  1.4.1-0ubuntu1 Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (64-bi
rc  wine1.4-i386:i 1.4.1-0ubuntu1 Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (32-bi
ii  wine1.6        1:1.6.1-0ubunt Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (Binar
```

you can see the first element is either `ii` or `rc`.

So my question what is the meaning of  `ii` and `rc`?

Comment: It wasn't like that. I really asked the question by time i found the link then when i see the answer is founded i marked as duplicate myself. It's not a game, It's self learning

Answer (score 2):

To get that you need to check the man page of `dpkg-query`. From `man dpkg-query` :

> The first three columns of the output show the desired action, the
>   package status, and errors, in that order.
>
> ```
>           Desired action:
>             u = Unknown
>             i = Install
>             h = Hold
>             r = Remove
>             p = Purge
>
>           Package status:
>             n = Not-installed
>             c = Config-files
>             H = Half-installed
>             U = Unpacked
>             F = Half-configured
>             W = Triggers-awaiting
>             t = Triggers-pending
>             i = Installed
>
>           Error flags:
>             <empty> = (none)
>             R = Reinst-required
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/status-dpkg-list/

Status of every package is represented by three characters xxx

The first character signifies the desired state

```
u: Unknown (an unknown state)
i: Install (marked for installation)
r: Remove (marked for removal)
p: Purge (marked for purging)
h: Hold
```

The second character signifies the current state, whether it is installed or not.

```
n: Not- The package is not installed
i: Inst – The package is successfully installed
c: Cfg-files – Configuration files are present
u: Unpacked- The package is stilled unpacked
f: Failed-cfg- Failed to remove configuration files
h: Half-inst- The package is only partially installed
W: trig-aWait
t: Trig-pend
```

The third Character corresponds to the error state.

```
R: Reinst-required The package must be installed.
```

Then

`rc` comes to packages remove with config files present

`ii` comes to packages marked for installation and it's successfully installed

Comment: edited to remove my downvote sorry